# jQuery .show/.hide/.toggle Not Working in Certain Circumstances

Tags: jquery, hide, toggle, show

I have 2 div's that I need consecutively toggled back and forth showing and not showing. Here is my current jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a:link').click(function(){
    $(".surveycontainer").toggle();
    $("#check").toggle();
    });

});
```

Note #check is hidden on page load via CSS so this script says when a link is clicked each will be toggled, making the "surveycontainer" div disappear and the "check" div appear and vice versa.

The script works fine when calling a RSS feed within the surveycontainer (containing a link) and when clicked each div's are toggled. The problem occurs when a plain link is placed in the div, when clicked the "surveycontainer" is hidden however "check" is not shown!

Surveycontainer code

```
<div class="surveycontainer" align="left">
<?php
// OFFERS

//Right here is a script that defines $country_code ("US" is what is called when the problem occurs)

<?php if($country_code=="US"): ?>
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Yahoo</a>

<?php else: ?>
//Calls a RSS feed containing links here

</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

As you can see if the $country_code equals "US" the Google link is called in a new window.

For some reason when the country code does not equal US and the data is pulled from the RSS feed the jQuery script above stands and each div is toggled when a link is clicked. However, when the Google link is used and clicked only the "surveycontainer" div is hidden and "check" is not shown.

I am in desperate need for a solution to this problem! Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

place `<?php endif; ?>` before `</div>` it is not giving to end your `surveycontainer` div
when condition for google link is satisfied. so re-writing your code will look like:

```
<div class="surveycontainer" align="left">
   <?php
   // OFFERS
   //Right here is a script that defines $country_code ("US" is what is called when the problem occurs)
   <?php if($country_code=="US"): ?>
      <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Yahoo</a>
   <?php else: ?>
       //Calls a RSS feed containing links here
   <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: It works! I can't believe that's all that was wrong. Thank you SO much! I can vote you as best answer is 7 minutes, I will be sure to do so. Thank you.

Comment: I am gald to help you ! If you had written formatted code, you would catch this mistake yourself :)

Comment: @user1067458 - note that if you are having trouble with PHP (or other-langauge server-side code) that outputs html or JS sometimes all it takes to spot the problem is to use "View Source" in the browser - in this case you would've seen that there was no `</div>`...

Comment: Thanks for the tip nnnnnn will be sure to use this before posting.